# Failed to prepare app package(s) because it is being used by another process

Tags: autodesk-forge

I can successfully process Revit models with now linked documents on Forge Design Automation, but when I try to process models with linked documents I get this error:

```
 Error: Failed to prepare app package(s). The process cannot access the file 'T:\Aces\Applications\Revit2ProtoExporter.zip' because it is being used by another process.
[11/06/2020 01:23:22] Error: Unable to download file https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/signedresources/5b476183-5bfb-4e98-8276-505dec9cc972?region=US: System.InvalidOperationException: DasZip failed with exit code = 1
   at CoreEngineRunner.DasZip.RunDasZipAsync()
   at CoreEngineRunner.DasZip.ExtractToDirectoryAsync(String sourceArchiveFileName, String destinationDirectoryName, String encoding, CancellationToken ct, Boolean isFaultTolerantOn)
   at CoreEngineRunner.DownloadItem.DownloadAsync(TraceSource logger).
[11/06/2020 01:23:22] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase Downloading of job.
[11/06/2020 01:23:22] Job finished with result FailedEnvironmentSetup
```

From what I can tell from the logs all the linked documents were successfully downloaded, so I am not sure what's going on. Below is the full log:

```
[11/06/2020 01:23:20] Job information:
"CommandLine":[
  "\"$(engine.path)/revitcoreconsole.exe /i $(args[rvtFile].path) /al $(appbundles[Revit2ProtoExporter].path)\""
]
"Settings":{
  "dasreportfaileduploadoptional": {
    "value": "true",
    "isEnvironmentVariable": true
  }
}
"Id":"8dff5a5fd1144e9e9302505e30987bdd"
"ActivityId":"WDQIfAV8PqNa9XSKPmv6MDu3xAtLGfXI.Revit2ProtoExporterActivity+AppliedVR50"
"Engine.Id":"Autodesk.Revit!39"
"Apps": [
"App.Id":"WDQIfAV8PqNa9XSKPmv6MDu3xAtLGfXI.Revit2ProtoExporter!55"
]
"BoundArguments":{
  "rvtFile": {
    "zip": true,
    "localName": "",
    "pathInZip": "root.rvt",
    "references": [
      {
        "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/Masked:Sae2ipw7szdulRannCn5DzwBuhM="
      },
      {
        "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/Masked:NPqlMsVOXAFdIg5sx5eIR2Y26HI="
      }
    ],
    "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/Masked:M+AnWc5OiowsRTaJvH8nPzTA9ao="
  },
  "params": {
    "localName": "params.json",
    "url": "data:application/json,{\"ViewId\": 7759865}"
  },
  "result": {
    "localName": "result.avr",
    "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/Masked:TFOCpwjedup6t/kPU2xq3JvGyfo=",
    "verb": "put"
  },
  "onProgress": {
    "ondemand": true,
    "url": "https://wlnr5sjl3a.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Masked:UK/Z3b5X3xUWxXiH6C9r9i9UlRU=",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "x-das-authorize": "awssigv4(us-east-1)",
      "x-ads-token-data": "{\"access_token\":{\"client_id\":\"WDQIfAV8PqNa9XSKPmv6MDu3xAtLGfXI\"},\"scope\":\"code:all data:write data:read bucket:create bucket:delete\",\"expires_in\":3569,\"client_id\":\"WDQIfAV8PqNa9XSKPmv6MDu3xAtLGfXI\"}"
    },
    "verb": "put"
  }
}
"Quotas":{
  "limitProcessingTimeSec": 10800,
  "limitTotalUncompressedAppsSizeInMB": 5000
}
[11/06/2020 01:23:20] Starting work item 8dff5a5fd1144e9e9302505e30987bdd
[11/06/2020 01:23:20] Start download phase.
[11/06/2020 01:23:20] Start downloading input: verb - 'GET', url - 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/signedresources/5b476183-5bfb-4e98-8276-505dec9cc972?region=US'
[11/06/2020 01:23:20] Start downloading input: verb - 'GET', url - 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/signedresources/c286f6d4-d6ac-45b8-84b7-7bd804d6cf35?region=US'
[11/06/2020 01:23:20] Start downloading input: verb - 'GET', url - 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/signedresources/66b668df-a639-4ba4-bb3b-2e2f35049365?region=US'
[11/06/2020 01:23:20] Embedded resource [{"ViewId": 7759865}] is saved as file: T:\Aces\Jobs\8dff5a5fd1144e9e9302505e30987bdd\params.json.
[11/06/2020 01:23:20] '4681728' bytes have been written to T:\Aces\Jobs\8dff5a5fd1144e9e9302505e30987bdd\9821ccb1a0bac5ffe69e46ca6d4ddde9.
[11/06/2020 01:23:20] End downloading file 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/signedresources/c286f6d4-d6ac-45b8-84b7-7bd804d6cf35?region=US'.
[11/06/2020 01:23:20] '4685824' bytes have been written to T:\Aces\Jobs\8dff5a5fd1144e9e9302505e30987bdd\d6b0fa35b9c5a76b8868f754562fbc09.
[11/06/2020 01:23:20] End downloading file 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/signedresources/66b668df-a639-4ba4-bb3b-2e2f35049365?region=US'.
[11/06/2020 01:23:21] '13568850' bytes have been written to T:\Aces\Jobs\8dff5a5fd1144e9e9302505e30987bdd\zip_21.zip.
[11/06/2020 01:23:21] End downloading file 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/signedresources/5b476183-5bfb-4e98-8276-505dec9cc972?region=US'.
[11/06/2020 01:23:22] Error: Failed to prepare app package(s). The process cannot access the file 'T:\Aces\Applications\Revit2ProtoExporter.zip' because it is being used by another process.
[11/06/2020 01:23:22] Error: Unable to download file https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/signedresources/5b476183-5bfb-4e98-8276-505dec9cc972?region=US: System.InvalidOperationException: DasZip failed with exit code = 1
   at CoreEngineRunner.DasZip.RunDasZipAsync()
   at CoreEngineRunner.DasZip.ExtractToDirectoryAsync(String sourceArchiveFileName, String destinationDirectoryName, String encoding, CancellationToken ct, Boolean isFaultTolerantOn)
   at CoreEngineRunner.DownloadItem.DownloadAsync(TraceSource logger).
[11/06/2020 01:23:22] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase Downloading of job.
[11/06/2020 01:23:22] Job finished with result FailedEnvironmentSetup
[11/06/2020 01:23:22] Job Status:
{
  "status": "failedDownload",
  "reportUrl": "https://dasprod-store.s3.amazonaws.com/workItem/WDQIfAV8PqNa9XSKPmv6MDu3xAtLGfXI/8dff5a5fd1144e9e9302505e30987bdd/report.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=ASIATGVJZKM3DKXULYFE&Expires=1604640200&x-amz-security-token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEKH%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJIMEYCIQD30WUuRtM0iuIWxkOah9t90%2B96TOt0DkqqAjHwzTuSKwIhAOm8LiqpZlwCDr6Ah4YWCzhSZ8xq0zzP4KRBHY2L0uMPKt4BCPr%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEQAhoMMjIwNDczMTUyMzEwIgyxm%2BA7M7tzSCXAOAQqsgGayvqco1UE6lJY%2Fzm6Q%2BFcoeJvpYXKN%2Fbx8o6B2DqoExa14uAjmS9GkYaAr1GXX%2B1YUgHJqU1EhJK9A1IUe41I0VnrujiHpMF8h3zlQEJ3q%2Fhrxg7%2BPND7RaBmy9dLYrS4giEwcmw0LvLNhGQcX56DDbsrqn94fgseSnGXa8VzikJVRHJcW3QU2%2BTD95fED8Ti6FJlHr1cwnXrKXK%2FUpsa8sbXCl1AW8prMb3kwhQQBC5XMPS9kv0FOt8BYzfwE32Tqa95uBxIX4yKHW3r2VHUr7ERl6vbP%2BSbCL2%2BFjRWeBUnKhwvyhvu6qyRmncho5VMdtxZv%2FyRK3l3%2BYykUO%2BKOVWxuku1nD1gxdqrcq4Kydz4DDluNPxsgNr3Vm9ewRAdzYS9ANmHysWWVRFFB81rOmWUPgrpbTKiX8dCqvZKSjkoLXNKXGaYkYmnDHS0qymqF353mLw42D9%2FoRgLbqQBI0EJDrielO1L%2Fxh%2BsN7vRsch3XA2YywIIc1ZnQnfbsWaH7DvmgK43DC5RFRffsVtMek9%2FyGlzsgYhg%3D%3D&Signature=eXSYaQ493438TS381AOIZ6rFfBY%3D",
  "stats": {
    "timeQueued": "2020-11-06T01:23:20.2861629Z",
    "timeDownloadStarted": "2020-11-06T01:23:20.6030353Z"
  },
  "id": "8dff5a5fd1144e9e9302505e30987bdd"
}
```

Comment: thanks for reporting @EhsanBarekati. We will get back to you.

Comment: I checked the log, I saw an error of `System.IO.IOException: The file 'T:\Aces\Jobs\8dff5a5fd1144e9e9302505e30987bdd\params.json' already exists`, this could fail the job at very beginning. Did any input zip file also contains "params.json"?

Comment: Hi Emma, yeah submitting the Revit file just by itself seem to have fixed the issue.